# Should I use UUID everywhere or is it alright to mix with usual IDs?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, primary-key, uuid

I've chosen to use UUIDs as primary key for all of my tables in DB. But I still have Django default tables like Groups, Permissions, Django_admin_log, etc. Should I override them to make the pk UUID or should I leave it like that?
Leaving it usual integer is simpler of course, but I feel like mixing usual ids and UUIDs in the database is at least confusing. I don't have explicit need to override them to use UUID, but still I can't come up with the conclusion.

Comment: I don't see any issue mixing them. In some situations an auto-incremented integer makes more sense and in some situations a UUID makes more sense. Especially if all of the integer ID entries exist only in the default Django tables, I would say don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

UUID's have more storage overhead than serial integers.  For this reason I would recommend that they be used only where there is a general benefit for them.  You didn't specify which database you are working with but it is possible you could end up bumping other columns to extended storage (and therefore forcing implicit joins).

If your tables are fairly narrow and you don't have to query on id ranges, then it makes little difference.